# Preventing dictionary user names for registration

Tags: user-registration

When I was setting up an account with gmail few years back (probably this is still a case, haven't check) I've noticed that system doesn't allow to register common terms, nouns as username, it seemed that it used a sort of dictionary for screening. I would like to implement similar feature in my app, anyone have idea how to tackle this? App is written in PHP but understand I'll have to hook it up with online service.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress MU has such feature too, you fill a list of possible usernames that you want to avoid and they become unavailable for users. You can check its source to get their approach...

Sinan.

Answer (score 0):

Well the API will vary from service to service so I'd suggest you find one, look at their developer docs and *then* if you have a question ask it here.